# не могу вычесть из счетчика 1

Tags: pascalabc.net

помогите, плиз.
хочу написать простенькую "игру", где каждые 0.5 сек. с рандомными координатами появляется объект, пользователь должен его "удалить" с помощью ПКМ, но, если на экране 10 объектов, то игра прекращается.
вопрос в том, что к счетчику прибавляется 1, когда объект появляется, но я не знаю как сделать так, чтоб от счетчика вычиталась единица, когда пользователь удалит объект.
думаю, проблема ясна.

```
uses abcobjects, graphabc;

procedure deleteobj(x, y, mb: integer);
begin
  case mb of
    2:
      begin
        var ob := objectunderpoint(x, y);
        if ob <> nil then ob.Destroy;
      end;
    end;
end;

begin
  window.Width := 640;
  window.Height := 360;
  window.Caption := 'MyGame';
  window.Fill('.../font.jpg');
  var i:=0;
  while i<10 do
    begin
      onmousedown := deleteobj;
      var x1 := random(515 - 63 + 1) + 63;
      var y1 := random(254 - 53 + 1) + 53;
      pictureabc.create(x1, y1, '.../object.jpg');
      inc(i);
      sleep(500);
    end;
end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var i := 0;

procedure deleteobj(x, y, mb: integer);
begin
  case mb of
    2:
      begin
        var ob := objectunderpoint(x, y);
        if ob <> nil then 
        begin
          ob.Destroy;
          Dec(i);
        end;
      end;
    end;
end;

begin
  window.Width := 640;
  window.Height := 360;
  window.Caption := 'MyGame';
  window.Fill('.../font.jpg');
  //var i:=0;
  while i<10 do
    ...
```

Comment: огромное спасибо!!
2 часа думал

Comment: @ksilusm Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.